# Parse.com PFQueryTableView didselect row UIWebview

Tags: xcode, storyboard, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com's PFQueryTableView.

Is there any way I can use didselect row to programatically send a PFObject (url) to a UIWebview ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested they can download and implement SVWebViewController.

And use the following code.

My .H file has the following.

```
...
@interface HomeworkSiteViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
{

    NSArray *sectionsArray;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sectionsArray;
@end
```

My .m file has the following.

```
@implementation HomeworkSiteViewController
@synthesize sectionsArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
```

...
// Retrieve objects from parse in background and store into NSArray. ( I stored mine in ArrayDataDesription )

//Then store the array you got from parse ( ArrayDataDesription ) into sectionsArray so that you can access it in didSelectRow using the following..

```
self.sectionsArray = ArrayDataDesription;
```

Then in didSelectRow initiate SVModalWebViewController..

For "initWithAddress:" access the url from your array.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:[[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"href"]];
    [self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

}
```

BTW I'm a noob at developing apps. Sooo... this may NOT be the best way to do this. But, it worked for me.